# Unable to access windows server in ec2 instance after domain change via rendom

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, server, amazon-ecs, rdp

I was setting up active directory in windows server 2016 in AWS EC2 instance. I was changing the local domain via rendom and after a restart, I am not able to log in again.

screenshot of th error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcDLF.png)

Comment: did you try logging in with a domain user ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried logging in with the domain user. The credentials are matching. But the local session was not able to start